# IBM Worklight 6.1 - Can't view/open a recorded test suite

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-mtww

I am trying to create a Test from recording (inside an Android emulator) using IBM Mobile Test Workbench for Worklight (Eclipse Juno SR2 - WL 6.1 - Workbench 8.5.1.2).

I installed the mobile client, start recording an application, created the test-recording which generated a test suite file. 
The problem is that after the testsuite is generated and I open it, Eclipse is displaying each millisecond a dialog:

> The file has been changed on the filesystem. Do you want to load the
>   changes?

I cannot click on Yes or No because other dialogs appear (and so on).
I've noticed that Eclipse is doing some side operations: verifying resource IDs, Reindexing the repository after I generate a managed application.

How can I view&execute the recorded test?

Comment: Have you made sure to follow the instruction steps here? http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r1m0/topic/com.ibm.rational.test.lt.mob.wl.ditaval.doc/topics/t_run_wb.html

Comment: I did not get to that point yet. I was blocked here after I did the steps in here: http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/wrklight/v6r0m0/topic/com.ibm.worklight.mobtest.doc/topics/t_rec_test_wb.html

Comment: I've set up a new Eclipse Kepler SR1 with WL Dev Edition + Mobile RTW for WL and the error is still there. <br> See some pictures here: https://onedrive.live.com/#cid=A7AB3515D88063AD&id=A7AB3515D88063AD%212076&v=3

Comment: I have created a new test project and opening the tests is working fine. Then I noticed that the first project was using Git. So the projects that are using Git are experiencing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to come from an external reason to Eclipse (this usually arrives when the file is modified by an external source). Have you an anti-virus installed on your laptop ? if yes, can you (temporally) stop it ?

Comment: I've stopped the antivirus (temporarily) and still the same behavior.

Comment: Once I remove the .ma and testsuite files, I don't get "Verifying ..." messages anymore...

Comment: In a way, you are right since it relates only to projects that use Git.